# Submersions and regular points

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, nonlinear-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. $V\subset X$ open and $G:V\subset X \to Y$ differentiable function.

If $u\in X$ is a critical point of $G$, then the linear mapping $dG(u): X \to Y$ is not surjective.

**My Questions**: If $u \in X$ is not critical, then must it $dG(u)$ be surjective? 
have a regular point always surjective derivative? 
Is the derivative at any regular point a submersion?

Comment: yes to first two simply by definition. for the third, what do you mean by 'derivative at any regular value?' regular value is an element of the target space, not the domain, so your statement doesn't make sense. I suggest going over the definitions again.

Comment: You are right. My mistake while typing the question. I corrected it now.

Comment: What is the definition of critical and regular values in the infinite dimensional setting? Note for example that for the map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$, $x\mapsto (x,0)$ every point is a regular point, ie not critical, but the differential is never surjective.